# the k&r c answer book exercise 1.13

Tags: c

I am studying this book but unfortunately get stucked in this question, I google others answer but I still have something that I don't understand

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXHIST 15
#define MAXWORD 11
#define IN 1
#define OUT 0

main() {
  int c, i, nc, state;
  int len;
  int maxvalue;
  int ovflow;
  int wl[MAXWORD];

  state = OUT;
  nc = 0;
  ovflow = 0;

  for (i = 0; i < MAXWORD; ++i)
    wl[i] = 0;
  while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t') {
      state = OUT;
      if (nc > 0)
        if (nc < MAXWORD)
          ++wl[nc];
        else
          ++ovflow;
      nc = 0;
    } else if (state == OUT) {
      state = IN;
      nc = 1;
    } else
      ++nc;
  }
  maxvalue = 0;
  for (i = 1; i < MAXWORD; ++i)
    if (wl[i] > maxvalue)
      maxvalue = wl[i];

  for (i = 1; i < MAXWORD; ++i) {
    printf("%5d - %5d : ", i, wl[i]);
    if (wl[i] > 0) {
      if ((len = wl[i] * MAXHIST / maxvalue) <= 0)
        len = 1;
    } else
      len = 0;
    while (len > 0) {
      putchar('*');
      --len;
    }
    putchar('\n');
  }
  if (ovflow > 0)
    printf("There are %d words >= %d\n", ovflow, MAXWORD);

  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

Here I can understand the most of code here,  but what  the meaning of less than 0?

```
  for (i = 1; i < MAXWORD; ++i) {
    printf("%5d - %5d : ", i, wl[i]);
    if (wl[i] > 0) {
      if ((len = wl[i] * MAXHIST / maxvalue) <= 0)
        len = 1;
    } else
      len = 0;
    while (len > 0) {
      putchar('*');
      --len;
    }
    putchar('\n');
  }
```

I know the author try to nomorize  the "len",but  why the len is less
 than 0? Why does it happed? I think it is postive value. In the
 condition of "if(  )" ，the "wl[i]" is positive.

Comment: I don't see a "len is less than 0", `len > 0` means _is len greater than 0_.

Comment: Also if this was not your misunderstanding: You should also tell us what the auther wants to solve with this algorithem.

Comment: @herring This is just a very bad code.:)  Take into account that indices of arrays start from 0.

Comment: I am sorry.This part is "((len = wl[i] * MAXHIST / maxvalue) <= 0)"

Comment: @Ackdari  the author say the "len" equal to "the frequency of the  wl[i]" happen in the MAXHIST .

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow  The code  is artificial and hard to  understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You refer to `if ((len = wl[i] * MAXHIST / maxvalue) <= 0)`.

Since any `wl[i]` will be `>=0`, and `MAXHIST` is `>0` and `maxvalue` will be `>=0`, then indeed `len` will never be less than zero and a comparison of `==0` would suffice.

However, always testing for the largest valid range is considerd good programming and is called *"defensive programming"* as it guards the program against current and future errors.

<sub>Example: would `MAXHIST` be made very large in the future, and `wl[i]` could become very large in the future, then the multiplication could wrap, resulting in a negative value.</sub>

Comment: why  don't we  use "if ((len = wl[i] * MAXHIST / maxvalue) >= 0)" instead?  When len <=0,it give "len =1" ,then the condition in the while will satisfy.    How can make it happen?  I think most time the  len should be great than 0.